# Nevanlinna–Pick interpolation of two sets of points on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, interpolation

Given that $z_1, z_2, w_1, w_2 \in D = \{z: |z| < 1\}$ and $\left| \frac{w_1 - w_2}{1 - w_1 \overline{w_2}} \right| \leq \left| \frac{z_1 - z_2}{1 - z_1 \overline{z_2}} \right| $, how do you actually find a holomorphic function such that $f(z_1)= w_1$ and $f(z_2) = w_2$? 
Is there a way to go trace the proof of the Schwarz-Pick theorem backwards?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to revert your last edit, because it removed information that was relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably looking for is a holomorphic function mapping
the unit disk $\Bbb D$ *into itself* with $f(z_1)  = w_1$ and
$f(z_2) = w_2$. Yes, you can proceed similarly as in the 
[proof of the Schwarz–Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem)
by "normalizing" one source point and its image to the origin:

$$
 T(z) = \frac{z - z_2}{1 - z\overline{z_2} } \quad \text{and} \quad
 S(w) =  \frac{w - w_2}{1 - w\overline{w_2} }
$$
are [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) mapping the
unit disk onto itself, and 
$$
 \lambda = \frac{S(w_1)}{T(z_1)}
$$
satisfies $\lvert \lambda \rvert \le 1$. Now verify that
$$
f(z) = S^{-1}(\lambda T(z))
$$
has the desired properties.